# Dell latitude doesn't get past Dell splash screen

Tags: 12.10, boot, dell, uefi

I got this new Dell Latitude E6420, I installed ubuntu 12.10 which works fine except for one issue. After I press the power button it hangs at a Dell splash screen and doesn't do anything. If I press F12 (before it hangs) to get in the boot selection and select one of the UEFI boot options all is well.

The problem of course is that it's a bit annoying to do this every time I boot. I ran boot-repair, but that didn't help (see http://paste.ubuntu.com/5643012/)

See https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv59J.jpg for my bios settings / boot menu. The ubuntu boot option is the one that appeared after I initially installed ubuntu, the other one appeared after running boot repair. I also made some boot options myself and pointed them to the correct grub file, but they had exactly the same issue.

I have HD encryption on, so maybe this has something to do with it, although the decryption comes after the boot menu, so it might be irrelevant. Also ubuntu is the only OS, so no dual booting is going on.

Comment: Did you try to disable Legacy BIOS, perhaps it gets lost trying to find a boot loader in the MBR, which is not there (line 6 of your boot-repair report). Also make sure the default entry in the UEFI boot menu is bootable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the BIOS there is an entry called Fastboot under POST behavior. There are three options: *minimal* (this was selected), *thorough* and *auto*. Setting it to *thorough* made me get passed the Dell splash screen. Then I got a message saying that no bootable devices where found, so I went back to the BIOS, made sure UEFI was selected and now it boots as expected!